# Create a fileshare without using portal or powershell in azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, fileshare

I setting up a environment clone in azure so i need my fileshares in one environment to be created in other environment using arm template or some othe r solution

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure storage file share, you can use Azure Powershell to create it.

```
$context= New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "" -StorageAccountKey ""

New-AzStorageShare -Name "your fileshare name" -Context $context
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-powershell.

Comment: I don't think the OP's question can be answered, as-is (the way it's written is very unclear and broad). They mentioned something about moving between environments (unclear what that means). Also, the title explicitly states that they do *not* want to use PowerShell, yet you provided an example in PowerShell.